# Sharing Laptops wifi internet to Desktop via ethernet

Tags: internet, ethernet, connection-sharing

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on a Dell Inspiron 530s. It has a Linksys network adapter card, but I do not have the adapter, so my computer is connection-less.

What I'd like to know is if there is a way to share the internet that my wireless laptop is receiving through an ethernet cord to give internet to my desktop computer. The laptop is a Compaq Presario CQ56, running Windows 8.

Any answer is well appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless are not able to connect to a physical ethernet card.

I assume you have following device.

PC A, installed windows, have wireless and wire internet connection
PC B, installed ubuntu, have wireless only.

And what you can do is share the following:
Share your PC A's wireless connection, and bridge PC A' wireless and wire if I am not remember wrongly. Connect PC B wireless to PC A's wifi network

Comment: PC B in this case is a desktop computer without wireless capabilities, so I'm trying to share my laptops connections to the desktop.

Comment: In this case, you need to configure your PC A connect internet by using wireless and share your PC A's internet through wire. And connect your PC B through wire through PC A.

Answer (score -1):

Configure your laptop as host for internetsharing, preferably with a running DHCP host service.
Ask on a Microsoft forum for details.